# mutate(percentage = n / sum(n)) - not correctly calculating percentage

Tags: r, percentage, dplyr

[Mutate output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuovT.png)

I have been working on the below code to calculate the percentages per hour (time column d h) for each behaviour however it is mixing up the order of the time column and incorrectly calculating the percentages. I have attached a sample of the output and some of the data. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
S06Behav <- S06 %>%
 group_by(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context)%>%
 summarise(count= n())

S06Proportions<-S06Behav %>%
 group_by(Time, PredictedBehaviorFull, Context) %>%
 summarise(n = sum(count)) %>%
 mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))
```

A sample of my data is https://pastebin.com/KE0xEzk7

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason the percentages are not being calculated as expected is because according to the code, you are determining the percentage based on 2 values which are the same, hence a proportion of 1.0.

I'm not fully sure from your question, but if when you say "*mixing up the order of the time column*", you mean the whole `Time` column is incorrect, then you might be better off using the `lubridate` package to make your `Time` column.

```
library(lubridate)

S06 %>% 
  
  # first we convert the Timestamp column into datetime format
  mutate(
    Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp)
  ) %>% 
  
  # then, we can extract the components from the Timestamp
  mutate(
    date = date(Timestamp),
    hour = lubridate::hour(Timestamp), 
    timestamp_hour = ymd_h(str_c(date, ' ', hour))
  ) %>%

  {. ->> S06_a} # this saves the data as 'S06_a' to use next
```

Then if I understand correctly you want to determine the percentage of observations of each behaviour type, per hour.

```
S06_a %>% 
  
  # then, work out the total number of observations per hour, context and behaviour
  group_by(timestamp_hour, Context, PredictedBehaviorFull) %>% 
  summarise(
    behav_total = n()
  ) %>% 
  
  # calculate the total number of observations per hour
  group_by(timestamp_hour) %>% 
  mutate(
    hour_total = sum(behav_total), 
    percentage = behav_total / hour_total
  )
```

Which produces the following output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   timestamp_hour [3]
  timestamp_hour      Context PredictedBehaviorFull behav_total hour_total percentage
  <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>                       <int>      <int>      <dbl>
1 2020-05-23 19:00:00 Present Bait                         1971       2184    0.902  
2 2020-05-23 19:00:00 Present Boat                           96       2184    0.0440 
3 2020-05-23 19:00:00 Present No_OP                         117       2184    0.0536 
4 2020-05-24 10:00:00 Absent  Bait                            9       1202    0.00749
5 2020-05-24 10:00:00 Absent  No_OP                        1193       1202    0.993  
6 2020-05-24 11:00:00 Absent  Bait                            5        129    0.0388 
7 2020-05-24 11:00:00 Absent  No_OP                         124        129    0.961
```

Comment: Thank you that one has worked really well!